# How to replace a view with another by clicking in a table row in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created a navigation menu with four item, now I want to link every item with a view controller, how I can do this?

I have used this tutorial: [How to create navigation panel](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift)

**CenterViewControllerDelegate**:

```
@objc
protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
  optional func toggleLeftPanel()
  optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak private var imageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak private var creatorLabel: UILabel!

  var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?

  // MARK: Button actions

  @IBAction func kittiesTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
  }



}

extension CenterViewController: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
  func ItemMenuSelected(ItemMenu: Menu) {
    imageView.image = ItemMenu.image
    titleLabel.text = ItemMenu.title
    creatorLabel.text = ItemMenu.creator

    delegate?.collapseSidePanels?()
  }
}
```

**SidePanelViewControllerDelegate**:

```
@objc
protocol SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
  func ItemMenuSelected(ItemMenu: Menu)
}

class SidePanelViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

  var ItemMenus: Array<Menu>!

  struct TableView {
    struct CellIdentifiers {
      static let MenuCell = "MenuCell"
    }
  }
    func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var tblView =  UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    tableView.tableFooterView = tblView
    tableView.tableFooterView!.hidden = true
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xE2F2C9)
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

}

// MARK: Table View Data Source


extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ItemMenus.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableView.CellIdentifiers.MenuCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell
    cell.configureForMenu(ItemMenus[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}

// Mark: Table View Delegate

extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedMenu = ItemMenus[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.ItemMenuSelected(selectedMenu)
  }

}

class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var ItemMenuImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageNameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageCreatorLabel: UILabel!

  func configureForMenu(ItemMenu: Menu) {
    ItemMenuImageView.image = ItemMenu.image
    imageNameLabel.text = ItemMenu.title
    imageCreatorLabel.text = ItemMenu.creator
  }

}
```